# how to define Angular8 Context Provider for global websocket variable

Tags: angular, angular-providers, angular-socket-io

I import **RecruiterAdminChatsComponent** at **AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { RecruiterAdminChatsComponent } from './recruiter-admin-chats/recruiter-admin-chats.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecruiterAdminChatsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and I defined the socket service at **app.comonent.ts** like the following

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SocketService } from '../_services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( private socketService: SocketService) {}
}
```

and to use **socketservice** at child component **RecruiterAdminChatsComponent**, I included the **socketservice**, too like the following.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SocketService } from '../_services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-recruiter-admin-chats',
    templateUrl: './recruiter-admin-chats.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./recruiter-admin-chats.component.scss'],
})
export class RecruiterAdminChatsComponent {
  constructor( private socketService: SocketService) {}
}
```

as you see, **SocketService** is inserted twice at parent component and child component.
I know that this is very bad thing.

how can I use the socketservice variable that is defined at parent just like react context?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `SocketService` under `providers` section in `AppModule`. It will make `SocketService` injected as Singleton.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecruiterAdminChatsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    SocketService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also, `SocketService` should be added `@Injectable`

```js
@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
}
```